An Integral Identity related to Mean Curvature
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. I want to prove the following integral identity:
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}H\langle x,\nu(x)\rangle dS(x)=|\partial\Omega|$$
where $H$ is the mean curvature, $\nu$ is the outward unit normal vector, $S$ is the surface measure, and $|\partial\Omega|:=\int_{\partial\Omega}1dS$. I don't know where to start and I did not find good references for this problem.

Why do you think this identity holds? Try checking it for the ball of radius $R$.

@Deane This is indeed true for the ball of radius $R$. In this case $H=1/R$ and $x=R\nu(x)$.

It's worth observing that this result is, in fact, translation-invariant because $\int_{\partial\Omega} \nu dS = 0$. But this observation also tells us that, despite appearances, the result is global, not local. My experience with integral geometry suggests that you might want to think about thickening $\partial\Omega$ by proceeding $\epsilon$ out along the normal; what is the volume of that tube to first order in $\epsilon$?
